# displaying images that recieved by websocket connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, video-streaming

we have websocket  connection and in this connection I received one image per secound.so my question is how can I display this image that is a blob format ? I have to use image tag or video play for it and how can I show this?

```
ws.onopen = e => {
        console.log(e)
    }
ws.onmessage = e => {

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); might works